# Jump to a specific section in a page -React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a footer components with some links which each one of them leads to a specific part of a page, how can I make the link jump to this specific part instead of routing only to that page.

`<li><Link to="/about-us/#section1">Our History</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/about-us/#section2">Our Mission</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/about-us/#section3">Our Values</Link></li>
    <li><Link to="/about-us/#section4">Become a Distributor</Link></li>`

I have tried the previous code using `id` of the same tag in the target section, but it didn't work.
Is there any other way to do that.

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you are using React Router, it does not have built in hash link support

You can use this library to accomplish instead:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-hash-link

```
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';
<HashLink smooth to='/about-us/#section1' > History </HashLink>
```

your section will need to have the id to match as well

```
<div id='section1'>Hi</div>
```

Comment: For the Single page, it's working fine but to navigate to a section of another page it's not working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use useRef hook.

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
```

Then

```
const section1 = useRef(null)
const section2 = useRef(null)
const section3 = useRef(null)

const scrollToSection = (elementRef) => {
window.scrollTo({
  top: elementRef.current.offsetTop,
  behavior: "smooth",
 });
};

return (
 <div className="App"> 
  <div>

   <ul>
    <li onClick={() => scrollToSection(section1)}>History</li>
    <li onClick={() => scrollToSection(section2)}>Mission</li>
    <li onClick={() => scrollToSection(section3)}>Values</li>
   </ul>

    <div ref={section1}>History</div>
    <div ref={section2}>Mission</div>
    <div ref={section3}>Values</div>

  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the React inclusions, use standard HTML bookmarking syntax when linking to an element on another page.

First import the hashlink library:

(may require an NPM install: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hash-link )

Now in your page's header/top area:

```
import { HashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link'
```

Now in your page's HTML/JSX section:

```
<HashLink to='/destination-page#destination-element-w-id'>Link-name</HashLink>
```

And of course, your destination element in the destination page must have an id:

```
<div id="destination-element-w-id">Your element</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a useEffect to handle the scrolling after entering a specific page. What happens is, after you get to the specific page, I check in useEffect if there are any hashes, and if so, scroll to them.

```js
useEffect(() => {
 window.scrollTo(0, 0);
 document.body.scrollTop = 0;
 const href = window.location.href.substring(
   window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') + 1,
 );
 if (window.location.href.lastIndexOf('#') > 0) {
   document.getElementById(href)?.scrollIntoView();
 }
});
```

I have also found and article about using forwardRef, perhaps this could also be useful for you? Although if you are linking from the footer, checking for hashes might be easier.
https://robinvdvleuten.nl/blog/scroll-a-react-component-into-view/