# reactjs - linking to div on same page?

Tags: html, reactjs

I have looked through some of the answers on stackoverflow and tried to resolve but still getting a:

> Cannot resolve anchor #how-it-works

```
<div className='container'>

    <section className="header-banner">
         <Link href="#how-it-works">
                <a className="btn-dca-form">How it works?</a>
         </Link>
    </section>
    <section id="how-it-works"> //I tried to use a section and tried using the div as well.
       <div className="row">
         <div className="col-12 col-sm order-5" style={{paddingTop: "55px"}}>
              <Fragment>
                   <Mock_Form/>
              </Fragment>
          </div>
       </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

I tried using standard `html` linking using `#how-it-works` and setting `id` of the `div`. That did not work either.

Comment: The `link` component already resolves as an anchor tag. You can't have an anchor tag inside an anchor tag.

Comment: @node_modules thank you, I changed that to a `btn` however it still will not link to the section.

Comment: I used the `HashLink` library using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525269/jump-to-a-specific-section-in-a-page-react. It would be great to see if there is anything else which can be done.

Comment: I mean, if you change `Link` to a normal `a` tag, it works so it's an issue of that library, or you're using it in a wrong way.