# When clicking a link, navigate to a specific element in React without scrolling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, user-profile

In my user's profiles page in React, when clicking on an image, it currently scrolls to that specific image within the entire images page. However, I want it to navigate directly to that image element without scrolling. I want to make this change because it becomes very lag when there are 100 pictures in a user's profile.

Is there any method in react or nextjs to achieve this?

Comment: Would you consider jumping to a detail page instead of srolling at the same page

Comment: When clicking on that image in the user's profile, it goes to another page. The image is also a link. The second page contains all the images of that user in full view, but to navigate to a specific image, scrolling is the only option

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58525269/jump-to-a-specific-section-in-a-page-react

Comment: That solution explains how to achieve scrolling to the page, and my page works for that. However, I want to navigate to a specific element without scrolling to it. Like clicking a post in any user profile in instagram app, it doesn,t scroll.

Answer (score -1):

You can create refs for each image and use the scrollIntoView method to bring the selected image into the view. Here's an example using React and Next.js:

1)Assuming you have a list of images in your component:

// ImageList.js

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const ImageList = ({ images }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={image.src}
          alt={`Image ${index + 1}`}
          onClick={() => handleImageClick(index)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

2. Now, in the same component or a parent component, you can define a ref for each image and create a function to handle the image click event:

// UserProfile.js

```
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import ImageList from './ImageList';

const UserProfile = () => {
  const imageRefs = useRef([]);

  const handleImageClick = (index) => {
    if (imageRefs.current[index]) {
      imageRefs.current[index].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>User Profile</h2>
      <ImageList images={yourImageArray} imageRefs={imageRefs} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserProfile;
```

3)In the ImageList component, update the img elements to use the refs:

// ImageList.js

```
const ImageList = ({ images, imageRefs }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {images.map((image, index) => (
        <img
          key={index}
          src={image.src}
          alt={`Image ${index + 1}`}
          onClick={() => handleImageClick(index)}
          ref={(ref) => (imageRefs.current[index] = ref)}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageList;
```

Comment: I tried this method, but it also scrolls from the top to that image. I pass the index through params; that image is from the user's profile page, and it represents a small view of that image. When clicking the image, it navigates to another page with all images of full view. Upon page load, I attempt to navigate to that element using the retrieved index. I am using the ref method or the getlelementByid method, but the behavior is such that when the page loads, it scrolls from the first image to the specified image. I want to display the specified image when the page loads.